# i am facing this issue while update the android studio 3.1.2

Tags: android

**"WARNING: Configuration 'androidTestCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'androidTestImplementation' and 'androidTestApi'."**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is only a warning, you can simple ignore that or you can get rid of this by changing all the `androidTestCompile` to `androidTestImplementation` in your gradle file

Answer (score 1):

I have also having **same Warning and solve by adding to `com.google.gms:google-services`** in my case.

The solution is to upgrade `classpath com.google.gms:google-services` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'` in file in **build.gradle**.

Comment: i also change this but still

Comment: you can also add  **apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'** in bottom of your **build.gradle**

Comment: please try with above, I hope it will help you

Comment: Sorry @Mohsan khan khichi to late response ? Is Your error solved? My answer is useful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

From gradle version 3.0.0 android studio have migrated to new dependency configurations

please go through the official documentations here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration